# Sympy: Why is cholesky not working for this symmetric matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

I would like to find a symbolic Cholesky factorisation with Sympy. The Matrix M (see example) is real symmetric (hence hermitian). But Sympy raises ValueError: Matrix must be Hermitian.

Two questions:

1. Why the error?
2. What do I need to do to find my Cholesky factors?

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')

M = Matrix([
    [ exp(x**2), exp(x*y)],
    [  exp(x*y), exp(y**2)]
])

print(M == M.T) #True
L = M.cholesky() #ValueError: Matrix must be Hermitian.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Matrix `M` is not Hermitian, because there is no restriction for values `x` and `y` to be complex.
2. Since `M` is not necessary Hermitian, you should use

   ```
   M.cholesky(hermitian=False)

   Out[17]: 
   Matrix([
   [         sqrt(exp(x**2)),                                       0],
   [exp(x*y)/sqrt(exp(x**2)), sqrt(exp(y**2) - exp(-x**2)*exp(2*x*y))]])
   ```

`hermitian` is a parameter that appears in `sympy version 1.4`. You can find changes [on this page](https://fossies.org/diffs/sympy/1.3_vs_1.4/sympy/matrices/matrices.py-diff.html). For earlier versions `cholesky` method works with your example as is.